# Is exposing my DSLR to a very intense source of direct light bad?

Tags: dslr, equipment-damage

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can the sun damage the camera sensor? Under what conditions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4016/can-the-sun-damage-the-camera-sensor-under-what-conditions)
>   [Can a laser pointer damage the sensor in a digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/can-a-laser-pointer-damage-the-sensor-in-a-digital-camera)

I'm wondering (mainly out of curiosity) if it is possible to damage a DSLR sensor and/or other parts of a camera by exposing them to a direct, extremely intense source of light such as direct sunlight or a laser pointer.

Does anyone know anything about this or can anyone point me to some litterature?
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4016/can-the-sun-damage-the-camera-sensor-under-what-conditions plus http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/can-a-laser-pointer-damage-the-sensor-in-a-digital-camera ; damage has been observed - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/how-to-fix-an-image-sensor-damaged-by-long-sun-exposures